# arrange the width tabularx{} with note

Tags: tables, tabularx

code below prints out a page-width table. If I try to customize `1\textwidth` it even looks worst. hope you may help, many thanks in advance.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,authoryear,sort&compress]{report}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabulary,array,tabularx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{table}[!ht]
    \centering
    \tiny % \footnotesize
    \begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth}{lc} % {0.75\textwidth}{l*{1}{C}} 
        \toprule
        &Estimate\\ 
        \midrule
        %Politicized recruitment & 0.030*(0.013) \\
        %(Intercept) & 3.445***(0.095) \\
        Politicized recruitment & 0.030* \\
        &(0.013) \\
        (Intercept) & 3.445***\\
        &(0.095) \\
        \midrule
        R-squared (adj.) & 0.098\\
        N & 3872 \\
        \bottomrule 
        \addlinespace
        \multicolumn{2}{@{}p{\textwidth}@{}}{\tiny Result from fixed effect regression with bootstrapped standard errors based on 2000 replications. Significance tests assume normal sampling distribution. Conditional R2 is calculated from all data. ‡ p < 0.100, * p < 0.050, ** p < 0.010, *** p < 0.001} \\
    \end{tabularx}
    %\caption{} 
    %\label{}
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: It makes no sense to use `tabularx` without specifying any `X` column.

Comment: as egreg says tabularx requires an X but `\begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth}{lX}` would still force the table to be full width, you could just use a normal tabular here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the earlier comments have pointed out (maybe somewhat implicitly), it's not necessary to employ a `tabularx` environment here. There's also no need to go `\tiny`.

Conversely, it looks like a good idea to align the numbers in the data columns on their decimal markers, which may be accomplished with the help of the `S` column type that's provided by the `siunitx` package -- which your code just so happens to load anyway. And, since you load the `threeparttable` package, you might as well use it to restrict the width of legend to that of the `tabular` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx,threeparttable,ragged2e}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!ht]
\sisetup{%
  input-symbols         = (),
  table-format          = 1.3,
  table-space-text-post = $^{***}$,
  table-space-text-pre  = ( }
    \centering
    \begin{threeparttable}
    %\caption{...} 
    %\label{...}
    \begin{tabular}{@{} w{l}{6cm} S @{}}  
        \toprule
        &{Estimate}\\ 
        \midrule
        Politicized recruitment & 0.030$^{*}$ \\
        &(0.013) \\
        Intercept & 3.445$^{***}$\\
        &(0.095) \\
        \midrule
        $R^2$ (adj.) & {0.098}\\
        $N$ & {3872} \\
        \bottomrule 
    \end{tabular}
        
    \footnotesize
    \RaggedRight 
    Result from fixed effect regression with bootstrapped standard 
    errors based on 2000 replications. Significance tests assume 
    normal sampling distribution. Conditional $R^2$ is calculated 
    from all data.

    \smallskip
    ‡ $p < 0.100$, * $p < 0.050$, ** $p < 0.010$, \mbox{*** $p < 0.001$}
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you very much for the response. but I do wonder why the code above does not work properly with {0.8\textwidth} when there is a note?

Comment: @SeymaKalay - I experience no difficulties at all if I replace `w{l}{6cm}` with `w{l}{0.8\textwidth}` and then recompile the test document. Hence, please clarify what you mean by "the code above does not work properly with {0.8\textwidth}".

Comment: I was saying for my code if I replace 1 with 0.8 or with any number  the note under the table exceeds the tables border.

Comment: Maybe because of  @{}p{\textwidth}{}. Anyway thanks a lot <3

Comment: @SeymaKalay - The code you posted initially was simply *wrong*, as you were employing a `tabularx` environment without at least one column having type `X`. If you don't believe me, please read the user guide of the `tabularx` package. To open this user guide in pdf viewer, just type `texdoc tabularx` at a command prompt.